# Want Git post receive hook to detect certain file types

Tags: git, file, git-post-receive

I would like my `post-receive` hook to run a certain script whenever
files of a certain type,   *.hbm.xml are pushed to the server.
Motivation: I want to rev my database schema version number whenever
NHibernate files are changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
for i in `git show --pretty="format:" --name-only HEAD | grep '.*\.hbm\.xml' `; do
    # call script here.....
    exit
done
```